# How to query a server linked via ODBC

Tags: ssms, linked-server, odbc

I've looked at multiple other questions about querying linked servers, but nothing has worked for my setup.

Notes:

- I'm not using localdb at all.  I just wanted to use SQLSMS for a remote cache database that is only accessible via the Intersystems ODBC driver.
- I edited out the actual table names, but they all have periods in them.
- MyDSN is not the actual DSN name.

Here is the structure and below the image are some of the things I've tried:

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM [MyDSN].[default].[Table.name]
```

> Invalid object name 'MyDSN.default.Table.name'.

```
SELECT * FROM [localdb].[MyDSN].[default].[Table.name]
```

> Could not find server 'localdb' in sys.servers.

```
SELECT * FROM [MyDSN].[default].dbo.[Table.name]
```

> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MyDSN" does not contain the table ""default"."dbo"."Table.name"".

```
SELECT * FROM [MyDSN]..[default].[Table.Name]
```

> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MyDSN" does not contain the table ""default"."Table.Name"".

```
SELECT * FROM [MyDSN].[default].[Table].[Name]
```

> Invalid object name 'MyDSN.default.Table.name'.

Also, if I right-click on one of the tables and pick "Script table as SELECT" I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Did you verify your ODBC DSN uses a valid login that can be authenticated by the remote server?  In other words, is the login defined in the DSN listed in the Security Tab for the linked server?

Comment: Yes, I meant to mention that.  I mean, it's listing the tables properly.  But also I right clicked on the link and verified it to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try Open query

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

select top 10  * 
INTO #t
from openquery ("YOUR LINKED SERVER NAME",'SELECT   * FROM [SOURCE TABLE NAME]);

COMMIT
```

Comment: hi. did you ever figure out a way without openquery? since i have the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately for you, but fortunately for me, I no longer work with Caché so I did not pursue this further. Sorry.